# C function to modify the value of a nested struct?

Tags: c, struct, nested

I have a nested structure in a separate header file (e.g. foo.h), like:

```
typedef struct signal
{
    struct asrengctrlactive
    {
        uint16_t SampleRate;
        uint32_t StartTime;
        uint16_t ValidRangeRaw;
    }ASREngCtrlActive;
        
    struct engspeed
    {
        uint16_t SampleRate;
        uint32_t StartTime;
        uint16_t ValidRangeRaw;
    }EngSpeed;   
} SIGNAL;
```

I'd like to have a function in main.c, which argument is the signal, what I want to use for modifying. I mean something like this:

```
void ModifyValue(signal, input)
{
    signal->SampleRate = input;
}
```

I'm not familiar in referring to a nested structure, can somebody help how can it be solved the cleanest way?

Comment: Since both structs are the same, it makes more sense to have a single struct definition, and two members of that type.

Comment: Note: both your structs are aligned badly.

Comment: You are right, I need to use multiple members, instead of multiple structs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following should work. In general, you should pass a pointer to the super-struct, dereference it with `->` and then access the nested structs members with `.`.

```
typedef struct signal
{
    struct asrengctrlactive
    {
        uint16_t SampleRate;
        uint32_t StartTime;
        uint16_t ValidRangeRaw;
    }ASREngCtrlActive;
        
    struct engspeed
    {
        uint16_t SampleRate;
        uint32_t StartTime;
        uint16_t ValidRangeRaw;
    }EngSpeed;   
} SIGNAL;

void ModifyValue(SIGNAL* signal, uint16_t input)
{
    signal->ASREngCtrlActive.SampleRate = input;
}
```

Note: If you don't pass the SIGNAL struct as a pointer, then all the modifications that will be performed by ModifyValue() will be lost after this function returns.

Comment: I want to use the ModifyValue to be parametrized, which struct I want to modify, therefore ASREngCtrlActive would be an argument. Is it feasible?

Comment: @T.Barta It would make sense to make the `ASREngCtrlActive` and `EngSpeed` members the same type (since they have identical members). Then you can parameterize it by passing a pointer to the member you want to modify. So instead of passing a `SIGNAL *` you would pass a pointer to the new type of those members.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but since you mentioned you were not familiar with referring to nested structures, note that the structure you posted is equivalent to:

```
struct asrengctrlactive
{
    uint16_t SampleRate;
    uint32_t StartTime;
    uint16_t ValidRangeRaw;
};

struct engspeed
{
    uint16_t SampleRate;
    uint32_t StartTime;
    uint16_t ValidRangeRaw;
};   

typedef struct signal
{
    struct asrengctrlactive ASREngCtrlActive;
    struct engspeed EngSpeed;   
} SIGNAL;
```

In other words, it makes no difference whether `struct asrengctrlactive` and `struct engspeed` are declared within `struct signal` or before it.

Whether or not the struct declarations are nested or not, the following code is valid:

```
void ModifyEngSpeedSampleRate(struct engspeed *eng, uint16_t rate)
{
    eng->SampleRate = rate;
}

void ModifySignalEngSpeedSampleRate(SIGNAL *signal, uint16_t rate)
{
    ModifyEngSpeedSampleRate(&signal->EngSpeed);
}

// (This modifies the nested member in a more direct way than above.)
void ModifySignalASREngCtrlActiveSampleRate(SIGNAL *signal, uint16_t rate)
{
    signal->ASREngCtrlActive.SampleRate = rate;
}
```

As was pointed out by user [interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay) in the comments to the question, it may make more sense to make the `EngSpeed` and `ASREngCtrlActive` members the same type. Although `struct asrengctrlactive` and `struct engspeed` are identical aside from their tags, they are treated as completely separate types because they have different tags.  The `ModifyEngSpeedSampleRate()` function above cannot be called with a pointer to the `ASREngCtrlActive` member because it has the wrong type.

For example:

```
typedef struct eng
{
    uint16_t SampleRate;
    uint32_t StartTime;
    uint16_t ValidRangeRaw;
} ENG;

typedef struct signal
{
    ENG ASREngCtrlActive;
    ENG EngSpeed;   
} SIGNAL;

void ModifyEngSampleRate(ENG *eng, uint16_t rate)
{
    eng->SampleRate = rate;
}

void ModifySignalSampleRates(SIGNAL *signal, uint16_t rate_e, uint16_t rate_a)
{
    ModifyEngSampleRate(&signal->EngSpeed, rate_e);
    ModifyEngSampleRate(&signal->ASREngCtrlActive, rate_a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm looking for a solution, which uses only one function for modifying. E.g like some comments above, I prefer to have a ModifyValue function, and one of its arguments is pointing to the nested structure, once to the EngSpeed, other times I call it to the ASREngCtrlActive. Then I do not need to write a function to every signal (like ModifyEngSpeedSampleRate() and ModifyASREngCtrlActiveSampleRate()), to modify the sample rate value.

Comment: @T.Barta Then use the same type for both members. I have added an example of that to my answer.